# Multiple arguments in slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots, slot, qspinbox

Want to pass two arguments to the slot. I have `ui->spinBox`, it has two signals `valueChanged(int)` and `valueChanged(QString)`. I'm doing like that:

```
connect(ui->spinBox,&QSpinBox::valueChanged, [&](){ this->ChangeParamCurve(ui->spinBox_11->value(),0);});
```

Appears error:

> error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
> qobject.h:463:41: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of
> 'valueChanged' matching 'const char *' for 2nd argument
> qobject.h:260:13: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
> template argument 'Func1' qobject.h:300:13: note: candidate template
> ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Func1' qobject.h:208:36:
> note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 4 arguments,
> but 3 were provided qobject.h:211:36: note: candidate function not
> viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
> qobject.h:228:43: note: candidate function template not viable:
> requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided qobject.h:269:13:
> note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4
> arguments, but 3 were provided qobject.h:308:13: note: candidate
> function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3
> were provided

I think that qt can't accept overloaded signals or smth like that.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not because of your slot but your signal. The solution is properly described in the documentation of [QSpinBox::valueChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged). Reading the documentation sometimes helps.

Comment: Thanks!Helped. How I pass over this?!My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) that @chehrlic pointed out, you need to use QOverload when connecting to this signal.

```
connect(spinBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
    [=](int i){ ChangeParamCurve(i, 0); });
```

Also, it doesn't matter how many parameters `ChangeParamCurve` takes. The lambda function is the slot that is being connected here. And it should take exactly one parameter, since that is what the signal is sending. But within the lambda, you can call functions with any number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive an object from the `spinbox` class yourself. You would be able to add signals and slots to it as you want.

I once did something like this because there was no "focus" event for `qlineedit`. Let me throw in the main idea of what I wrote for `qlineedit`.

If you want to have a focused signal, you will have to derive the `QLineEdit` class. Here is a sample of how this can be achieved.

In the `myLineEdit.h` file you have:

```cpp
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MyLineEdit();

signals:
  void focussed(bool hasFocus);

protected:
  virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
  virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
};
```

In the `myLineEdit.cpp` file you have:

```cpp
MyLineEdit::MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent)
 : QLineEdit(parent)
{}

MyLineEdit::~MyLineEdit()
{}

void MyLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
  QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
  emit(focussed(true));
}

void MyLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
  QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
  emit(focussed(false));
}
```

You can now connect the `MyLineEdit::focussed()` signal to your `focus()` method (slot).

In the same way two events can trigger your custom event with custom parameters. Again, if you wish, you can add these features to an existing `spinbox`, from the Designer, by right-clicking and using the `Promote to` method.